# select option based on requirement in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to change Upload file name when I select contributor it should show upload file and if I select editor it should show Upload Article.  I wrote the code but it is not working. Please help me.

This is source code of select button. you can see in image what is my question exactly.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Register As<sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" checked name="noaUserType" id="inlineRadio1" value="3"> Contributor
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="noaUserType" id="inlineRadio2" value="4"> Editor
        </label>
    </div>
</div>                          

<?php
if ($noaUserType == 3) {

    $file = "Upload Article";
} else {
    $file = "Upload File";
}
?>

<span id="noaSpanRegFileDivs">
    <div id="noaDivRegFile_1" class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo $file; ?><sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7 pos_r">
            <input type="file" name="noaRegnFiles[]" class="form-control" id="noaRegnFile_0" style="height:auto;">
            <div class="Addfile"><a href="Javascript:void(0);" id="noaBtnRegnFile_1" OnClick="noaRegnAddIFile(1);" class="btn btn-warning">Add File</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

[image: Link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using jQuery as below.

**Using jQuery =>**

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      if( $(this).val()=='4' )
      {
        $("#uploadtext").text("Editor");
      }
      else
      {
          $("#uploadtext").text("File");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Register As<sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" checked name="noaUserType" id="inlineRadio1" value="3"> Contributor
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="noaUserType" id="inlineRadio2" value="4"> Editor
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<span id="noaSpanRegFileDivs">
    <div id="noaDivRegFile_1" class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Upload <span id="uploadtext">File</span><sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>
    </div>
</span>
```

Comment: @Vasantha Mareddy. I am glad that this solution helped you. You can accept this answer and upvote it to mark this question as answered and close this thread. Thanks.